# Is it possible to log into multiple log files from a single module in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-logging

Is it possible to log into multiple log files from a single module in python 3.0, where the logs file are named based on some request parameter while using flask framework.

below code works fine if i run it like a single module and import but when i run using flask, it writes in the first attempt but later falls back to logging to the root logger.

I want a logging factory in flask that can check if the logger is already present and if already present than log in the same file and if not then create a new logger and log to the new file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def setup_logger( name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):

    my_file = Path(log_file)
    print(my_file)
    if my_file.is_file():
        print("handler details")
        print(logging.getLogger(name).hasHandlers())
        print(type(logging.getLogger(name).hasHandlers()))
        if logging.getLogger(name).hasHandlers():
            print("old logger and it has handler")
            logger.propagate = False
            return logging.getLogger(name)
        else:
            handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='a')        
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            logger = logging.getLogger(name)
            logger.setLevel(level)
            logger.addHandler(handler)
            logger.propagate = False
            print("old logger that has no handler")
            return logger
    else:
        handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='a')        
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        print("new logger with new handler")
        logger.propagate = False
        return logger
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67486803/14399185 -- I am looking for some help here.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was able to achieve the required functionality with the following method:

```
def setup_logger( name, log_file, level=logging.DEBUG): 

    my_file = Path(log_file)
    # print("check the if condition for the file")
    # print(my_file.is_file())

if my_file.is_file():
    #print(logging.getLogger(name).hasHandlers())
    # if logging.getLogger(name).hasHandlers():
    if len(logging.getLogger(name).handlers)>0:
        return logging.getLogger(name)
    else:
        handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='a')        
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.propagate = False
        return logger
else:
    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='a')        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.propagate = False
    return logger
```